# Input value resets when input is cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an input in a react component to store a name:

```js
<input key="marker-name" id="marker-name" name="marker-name" onChange={handleRename} type="text" value={name} />
```

I have written the following handler for it:

```js
const handleRename = ({ target }) => {
    setPerception({
      ...perception,
      name: target.value
    })
}
```

However, it's not working as expected, if a user tries to delete the existing name then as soon as the last character in the input is deleted (i.e. the input is empty) the previous value just pops back in.

[image: Example of problem]

Here is the full code of the component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// import custom styles for child component
import './styles.scss'

const MarkerName = ({ store, onStoreUpdate, callbackFunction }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
  const [perception, setPerception] = useState(null)
  const [currentMarkerName] = useState(store.currentMarkerName)
  const [currentMarkerForce] = useState(store.currentMarkerForce)
  const [currentForce] = useState(store.currentForce)

  // A copy of the store to capture the updates
  const newStore = store

  // Only populate the perception state if it's store value exists
  useEffect(() => {
    store.perception && setPerception(store.perception)
  }, [])

  // Only show the form to non-umpire players who cannot see the correct name
  const clickHander = () =>
    currentForce !== 'umpire' &&
    currentForce !== currentMarkerForce &&
    setClicked(true)

  const handleRename = ({ target }) => {
    setPerception({
      ...perception,
      name: target.value
    })

    newStore.perception.name = target.value
    onStoreUpdate(newStore)
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e && e.preventDefault()
    callbackFunction(newStore)
  }

  const handleRevert = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setPerception({
      ...perception,
      name: null
    })
    newStore.perception.name = null
    onStoreUpdate(newStore)
    handleSubmit()
  }

  const name = perception && perception.name ? perception.name : currentMarkerName

  return (
    <>
      <h2 key="header" onClick={clickHander}>{name}</h2>
      {
        clicked &&
        <div className="input-container marker-name">
          <label>
            Update asset name
            <input key="marker-name" id="marker-name" name="marker-name" onChange={handleRename} type="text" value={name} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Rename</button>
          <button onClick={handleRevert}>Revert</button>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default MarkerName
```

Comment: Can you please add all the component code?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this line is the problem:

```
const name = perception && perception.name ? perception.name : currentMarkerName;
```

You are re-rendering on every character change (`onChange={handleRename}`). As soon as all characters are deleted `perception && perception.name` is evaluated to `true && false` (empty strings are falsy) which is `false`. So the component is rendered with `const name = currentMarkerName`. As  `currentMarkerName` hasn't changed yet, it is re-rendered with the old name.

Use this instead:

```
const name = perception && typeof perception.name !== 'undefined' ? perception.name : currentMarkerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React forms are controlled components, You were almost getting it but at that point where you checked for the value of perception before assigning to the inputValue...that does not seem right.

Could you try to make these changes and let us see the effect:
1. For the state value of perception, make the initial value any empty string:
`const [perception, setPerception] = useState(null)`

2. On the forminput use
3. The handleRename function could just be declared as 
   `const handleRename = (e) => {e.target.name: e.target.value}`